# AlertView и лишний мусор

Tags: objective-c

Доброго времени суток! Насколько я знаю с ios 8 нужно вызывать метод

`requestWhenInUseAuthorization`
для геолокации.

Как этот алерт можно изменить ? написать все на русском например. 
И как сделать так чтобы до выбора кнопки не выполнялось никакие методы.

Спасибо.

[image: картинка]

Comment: а вы это на симуляторе запускаете или не устройстве?

Comment: На симуляторе .

Comment: говорят на девайсе этот текст должен быть на языке установленном в телефоне. а поменять его вы не можете (см ответ ниже)

Comment: Печально конечно. По поводу второго вопроса, как реализовать чтобы остальные методы описанные далее не выполнялись пока пользователь не сделает выбор. А то так получается что пока висит этот вопрос, остальные методы от которых зависит вопрос уже выполнились....

Comment: я вам в том вопросе написал - весь свой код вызывайте из didUpdateLocation

Answer (score 0):

Это системный алерт. Он сам локализируется в зависимости от языка дейвайса. Стать его делегатом вы тоже никак не сможете. Это - permission alert для запроса пользовательского разрешения на использование его геолокации. Вы можете только выбрать момент когда этот алерт вызвать, не более.